# How to assert *ast.StructType to specified interface

Tags: go

Can I assert a struct represented by *ast.TypeSpec and *ast.StructType to implement a known interface type?

For example

```
func assertFoo(spec *ast.TypeSpec) bool {
    // spec.Name == "MyStruct"
    st, _ := spec.Type.(*ast.StructType)
    // I want to know whether "MyStruct" implements "FooInterface" or not
    _, ok := st.Interface().(FooInterface)
    return ok
}
```

but there is no `*ast.StructType.Interface()` :(

Comment: If you have an instance of a known type, then you know what interfaces it implements at *compile time*. Just convert it to said interface. There's no runtime assertion, because it makes no sense.

Comment: I don't have any instance of the type, because this code is a piece of framework. For example, developer wrote `fw.Controller`-like struct, I want to validate it to implements `fw.Conttoller` interface.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do this strictly from the AST?? The AST has no type information, it's just the parsed Go source code. Your question sounds like you're just trying to do what the compiler already does for you, but if you want to go further down this path, you'll need at least [go.types](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.tools/go/types)

Comment: Yes. I wanna parse Go source code, and generate other Go source code automatically. Thank you very much and I'll try [go.types](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.tools/go/types) :)

Answer (score 2):

The first question would be what are you trying to do?

Compile time check is easy (compiler error if the interface is not implemented):

```
func assertFoo(t *ast.StructType) {
    var _ FooInterface = t
}
```

But you don't even need the actual value and can write this as:

```
func assertFoo() {
    var _ FooInterface = (*ast.StructType)(nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much and I'm sorry for poor explanation. I want to assert **a struct represented by StructType** to be a interface, NOT StructType itself. I updated the question. Thank you.